# Problem with CRS re-projection for a clipping a vector layer (EPSG 3035 to 4326) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, clip

I want to clip my vector layers depicting species occurrences in a german area with a polygon that I drew from a previous project. Here is my problem, species layers are in EPSG 4326 and my polygon (called Ueckermunde-shape)from a previous project is EPSG 3035.

When I re-project species occurrences in 3035 both layers do not meet. When I reproject the polygon in 4326 and eventually clip my species layers (species layers being input layer in the clipping process) the attribute table of species layers become null.
It is strange because even when all layers have been changed in 4326 and I want to clip my species layer, my polygon is displayed in 3035... see img attached :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you right click your layer and set a different CRS it is not properly reprojected - it is only done by QGIS "on the fly". To properly reproject, right click your layer -> export and save it again, but change the CRS to your desired CRS! Load this layer to your project and your clipping should work as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Right-clicking on the layer name and changing the `Layer CRS` does not reproject the layer.

Doing so, instead, informs QGIS that you want it to handle the layer as if it were on the assigned CRS, in other terms you are "forcing" QGIS to use the layer's data in the wrong projection/CRS.

I am quite sure all subsequent problems derive from this action.

I would suggest to:

1. remove all involved layers from the project,
2. add them again: QGIS will load them with the correct CRS
3. just perform the clippling: all reprojection processes will be handeld internally by QGIS.